# Intrinsic camera parameter from three vanishing points

Tags: geometry, matlab, matrix-equations

I would like to recover the intrinsic parameter from three vanishing points of a digital image. I read a bit on the famous textbook *[Multiple View Geometry in Computer Vision](http://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/~vgg/hzbook/)* (pag. 226) but I couldn't be able to get a satisfactory result.
In detail I need to recover the *K* matrix with three unknowns: focal length *f*
, *u* and *v*. It can be considered as a simplified case where *K* has the form:
$$
K = \begin{bmatrix}f & 0 & u\\0 & f & v\\0 & 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}
$$
I start from three vanishing points in pixel coordinates, calculated as the intersections of three sets of parallel lines. They are in the form:
$$
V_1 = \begin{bmatrix}x_1\\y_1\\1\end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}212\\2138\\1\end{bmatrix},
V_2 = \begin{bmatrix}x_2\\y_2\\1\end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}-49\\42\\1\end{bmatrix},
V_3 = \begin{bmatrix}x_3\\y_3\\1\end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}1105\\146\\1\end{bmatrix}
$$

The author suggests to consider this matrix $\omega$:

$$
\omega = \begin{bmatrix}\omega_1 & 0 & \omega_2\\0 & \omega_1 & \omega_3\\\omega_2 & \omega_3 & \omega_4\end{bmatrix}
$$
and recover its values by the orthogonality property of vanishing points, stacking three equations as constraints:

$$V_1^T*\omega *V_2=0$$

$$V_1^T*\omega *V_3=0$$

$$V_3^T*\omega *V_2=0$$
This will generate a linear matrix equation of the form $A_{3,4} * \omega_{4,1} = 0_{3,1}$. Then $\omega$ can be calculated as the nullspace of $A$. Finally $K$ can be recovered by a Cholesky factorization as $\omega = (KK^T)^{-1}$.

Here my $\omega$ matrix:
$$
\omega = \begin{bmatrix}1.6372\cdot 10^{-6} & 0 & -6.2870\cdot 10^{-4}
\\0 & 1.6372\cdot 10^{-6} & -4.7153\cdot 10^{-4}\\-6.2870\cdot 10^{-4} & -4.7153\cdot 10^{-4} & 1\end{bmatrix}
$$
which gives me

```
K = chol(inv(w));
```

$$
K = \begin{bmatrix}921 & 193 & 0.970\\ 0 & 841 & 0.396 \\0 & 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}
$$
Unfortunately the results are not like expected: $K$ matrix presents non-zero term in position (1,2) and difference between term (1,1) and (2,2). I think I did some mistake all they way through.
Could you help me in any way? Maybe pixel coordinates aren't right for this procedure?

I link here a picture rapresenting the scene [image]

Comment: It came out I was wrong on the last step. Instead of K = chol(inv(w)) I had to do K = inv(chol(W)). Now u and v are centered. Moreover, using original image size (8Mpx) we get a f-value of 2628, which is quite accectable considering the camera is 3264x2448 px, sensor is 4.8x3.6 mm, and real focal is 3.7 mm, a bit more than 2500 px.